# Admob test ads appearing in Unity Editor but not in finished game build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, admob, editor

I've got a bit of an issue here. I'm using the test adds and a test ID (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111) to make sure I don't cause any problems while still debugging my game.

However, the banner and interstitial ads I've added to the game only appear when I'm running in editor (over unityRemote so I can test directly on my phone).

When I try to build and run the same game (without changing any of the IDs) none of the ads appear. I even tried adding the Admob sample scene to the build so I could try the ads on those pages and once again, they work fine when in the editor, but completely fail to show when I build and run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors or messages in logcat?

Comment: Two errors that appeared as soon as I hit the "Request Interstitial" button on the sample page were: Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdError;
and Error Unity java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdError;

Comment: Check that the required modules are marked to be included in the build in the inspector. Running the resolver may help with this as well.